# iText PDF - can't export korean language

Tags: itext

I'm currently using iText PDF Lib (5.4.3)

When I used iText PDF ver 5.1.x

It's working good export Korean Language.

But when I changed latest version(5.4.3) .

It can't export Korean Language.

I was tried set Chartset also.

```
    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser(true, worker, Charset.forName("euc-kr"));

document.open();


xmlParser.parse(strReader);

document.close();
```

And I checked font(malgun.ttf) also.

But, still it's not working.

I don't know what I missed something... :(

Please help..

Thanks.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please read the changelogs of iText, more specifically for [version 5.2.0](http://itextpdf.com/history/?branch=52&node=520). From this version on, you need to replace the iTextAsian.jar (see [extra jars](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/extrajars/) directory) because we changed the way CJK fonts are used.